# Is it possible to get a WSDL 2.0 from JAX-RS annotated class?

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-rs

Is it possible to obtain a WSDL 2.0 from a JAX-RS annotated class? Do you know any libraries that do this?

ps. Maybe I can use Apache Axis2, Apache Woden or WSDL4J?

pps. Maybe it's possible to obtain WSDL from a POJO (without any annotations)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I end up using a combination of the following:

- [Apache Woden 1.0-SNAPSHOT](http://ws.apache.org/woden/) to create WSDL 2.0
- JAXB to discover data properties
- Java reflection to discover methods and their params

Comment: could you post your detail solution of creating the wsdl from your jax-rs classes?

Answer (score 2):

Are you developing the JAX-RS annotated class yourself? If not read no further, but if so: why not implement both JAX-RS & JAX-WS? It's relatively easy using for instance CXF.

I've got a sample project setup here: https://trac.nbic.nl/brsp201017/browser/tags/inchi2image-java/inchi2image
but there's loads more (and better!) samples & tutorials available if you want to implement both together..

What I've done is write an interface that I've annotated with JAX-WS's `javax.jws.WebService` & `javax.jws.WebParam`, and implement that interface in a class annotated with JAX-RS's `javax.ws.rs.Path`, `javax.ws.rs.GET`, etc.. The only tricky thing is getting your applicationContext.xml & web.xml right, but that's easy when you've got an example.

I'm not saying what I did is a good example to follow, but it works in my case. If this somehow does not match your question please let me know and I'll try to update my answer.

Comment: In my use case I want to generate and deliver WSDL myself, without JAS-WS implementation library. I'm building something alternative to JAX-WS/JAX-RS. That's why I need a library that will help me to generate WSDL from Java class.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want WSDL for a JAX-RS class? JAX-RS isn't a Web Services library - it's a library for building RESTful services running over HTTP.

If you want WSDL use CXF or Axis, or the Java EE web services annotations.

If you want to call a JAX-RS annotated class investigate the client libraries available from [RestEasy](http://jboss.org/resteasy) or [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/)

Comment: WSDL 2.0 supports REST, and is a good alternative to WADL. Unfortunately, JAX-RS doesn't support WSDL at all. Do you know how I can expose my RESTful services in WSDL 2.0?